# Receiving a reference error for Index Match, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel-formula

What is wrong with my index match statement? I am getting:

```
#REF! error
```

when I use:

```
=INDEX(VendorSub[@[Unique ID]],MATCH([@VendorName]],VendorSub[VendorName],0),2)
```

I have two sheets in same workbook. I need to lookup the UniqueID from VedorSub where the VendorName matches the VendorName in GCMainForm and then return the value in GCMainForm. The formula is being called from GCMainForm.

VendorSub
[image: =INDEX(VendorSub[@[Unique ID]],MATCH([@[7293_Vendor(s) currently working for]],VendorSub[Vendor/Subcontractor Name],0),2)]

GCMainForm

[image]

What am I missing?  If I am looking for the UniqueID for "AAA Fencing", it should return "18327".

Comment: `=INDEX(VendorSub[Unique ID],MATCH([@VendorName],VendorSub[VendorName],0))` you need to use the full column in the index and remove the 2, as there is only one column.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to a vlookup and was able to get the correct results.  Thanks for your input.

> `=VLOOKUP(Table1[@[7293_Vendor(s) currently working for]],VendorSub!A:B,2,0)`